# How to handle loading of specific file type in Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, vsix, vs-extensibility, vssdk

I have a Visual Studio solution inside a zip file and my plan is to unzip that file and then load the solution. Is it possible to do this with the Visual Studio API?

My first thought was to to implement [IVsProjectFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsprojectfactory?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and [IVsProjectUpgradeViaFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsprojectupgradeviafactory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to unzip the solution in the [CreateProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsprojectfactory.createproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsProjectFactory_CreateProject_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_UInt32_System_Guid__System_IntPtr__System_Int32__)/[UpgradeProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsprojectupgradeviafactory.upgradeproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsProjectUpgradeViaFactory_UpgradeProject_System_String_System_UInt32_System_String_System_String__Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsUpgradeLogger_System_Int32__System_Guid__) method and then load it.

Unzipping works, but when I try to load the solution file with [IVsSolution.OpenSolutionFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.opensolutionfile?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsSolution_OpenSolutionFile_System_UInt32_System_String_) or [DTE.Solution.Open()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionclass.open?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE_SolutionClass_Open_System_String_) (inside the CreateProject/UpgradeProject method), it fails with an ArgumentException.

Is there any solution to this problem? Ideally, it should behave just like opening a normal VS Solution (opening from Windows explorer, or Ctrl+o/Ctrl+Shift+o in Visual Studio).

**Edit**
I have managed to get it working by implementing an [IVsEditorFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivseditorfactory?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) which is associated with my file extension. When a file with that extension is opened, the [CreateEditorInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivseditorfactory.createeditorinstance?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsEditorFactory_CreateEditorInstance_System_UInt32_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsHierarchy_System_UInt32_System_IntPtr_System_IntPtr__System_IntPtr__System_String__System_Guid__System_Int32__) method is called where I unzip the file and then open the solution with IVsSolution.OpenSolutionFile().

Unfortunately, this does not allow me to open the file via File->Open->Project/Solution, but only via File->Open->File. Also, the dialog that shows up when opening the file is titled "Opening the file" not "opening the solution" or something like that.

This solution feels a bit like a hack, but until now I couldn't find another way. I'm still open for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to write a batch script to unzip the solution.
Following that it could **start solution_name**.  That ought to start MSVS on that solution.   In general issuing a START on any file type will try to open it with the default application.

Comment: This only works, when opening the file from the Windows Explorer. Opening the file from Visual Studio would open the solution in a new VS instance (actually, I think it would also be necessary to register the batch script for opening files with that specific file extension in the registry, otherwise VS will just show a hex dump of the file, even when I set the batch script for opening that file type through the Windows Explorer).

Comment: Humm.  I tried it from a dos window  "start project.sln"  Visual Studio started right up and the solution was opened. I'm in a win 10/MSVS 2017 context.  I guess it's a your mileage may vary situation.